# Every not-orientable $n$-manifold embeds in an orientable $(n+1)$-manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, orientation

I have to prove that **every not orientable smooth $n$-manifold $M$ can be embdedded in an orientable smooth $(n+1)$-manifold**. My idea is to use the embedding theorem of Whitney but it just says that there exists an embedding $f: M\to\mathbb{R}^h$ for some $h\ge 1$. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You could embed $M$ in a twisted $I$-bundle, where the twist is controlled by the orientation character. This manifold has boundary, but you can just glue it to another copy of itself (i.e. take the double).

Comment: I think that there should be a geometric version of this via a canonical orientation on the total space of $\Lambda^nT^*M$ and them embedding $M$ as the zero section.

Comment: @AndreasCap This is pretty interesting, can you give more details?

Answer (score 5):

Put $N:=\Lambda^nT^*M$ where $n=\dim(M)$, so there is a natural projection $p:N\to M$ and a point $y\in N$ with $p(y)=x$ is an $n$-linear alternating map $(T_xM)^n\to\mathbb R$. Then $T_yp:T_yN\to T_xM$ is surjective and the kernel of this map can be identified with $\Lambda^n(T_xM)^*$ itself. Now take a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $T_xM$ choose lifts $\tilde v_i\in T_yN$. Add the element in $\Lambda^n(T_xM)^*\cong ker(T_yp)$ that represents the unique multilinear map $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(v_1,\dots,v_n)=1$. Now consider the basis $\{\tilde v_1,\dots,\tilde v_n,\alpha\}$ for $T_yN$. A short computation (or a moment of thought) shows that starting from a different basis of $T_xM$, the resulting basis of $T_yN$ represents the same orientation. Thus you get a well defined orientation on $T_yN$ and it is easy to see that the resulting orientations are compatible, so this makes $N$ into an oriented manifold and then $M$ is embedded as the zero section.

Comment: To the OP:  I believe this constructs the same space as what Cheerful Parsnip suggested.  (In case it's not clear:  +1 from me - my previous sentence is in now way supposed to be a critique of this answer; it's intended to help guide the OP.)

Comment: I agree, as I said in my comment to the question I would view it as a geometric version of what @CheerfulParsnip suggested.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that!   I'll delete my first comment (and this one) in a few hours.

Comment: no worries, I think it is good to point it out once more.